# How to save the record only if checkbox is ticked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i have model named `Item` with the fields of:

**shipped( boolean ), reached ( boolean ), shipped_at (date) and reached_at (date)**.

The shipped and reached fields are check boxes in the view.

Now when I add a new record in the `Item` model, I want the `shipped_at` date field and `reached_at` date field to be nil if the `shipped` and `reached` check box is not selected. If only one of them is selected i want the date for that particular one to be stored.

To accomplish this i have created before_save filter in my model :

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :dates_defaults

 def dates_defaults

  if(shipped = 0 || reached = 0) 
  self.shipped_at = nil || self.reached_at = nil
  end
    end
   end
```

This works fine fine if the check boxes are not ticked. But when they are, the date fields are still nil.

Do i need to add else statement in the `dates_defaults` method ? If yes, how ? Is this good way to check for boolean fields ? ( I know that some databases store them as 0 and 1 and some as T and F).

Is there some more 'rails style ' solution to this ?

Thank you .

Comment: Change "if(shipped = 0 || reached = 0)" to "if(shipped == 0 || reached == 0)"

No need to use self.shipped_at = nil || self.reached_at = nil, just write both from newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `if (shipped = 0 || reached = 0)` is using assignment `=` not comparison `==` so shipped is always zero, and since shipped (0) is "truthy" the second half of the condition is ignored.

Second, `self.shipped_at = nil || self.reached_at = nil` will always set both to nil.  Again, you're not using the comparison `==` and since the first part is nil the second part is always executed.

A better solution might be...

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :dates_defaults

  def dates_defaults
    self.shipped_at = nil unless shipped?
    self.reached_at = nil unless reached?
  end

end
```

If shipped and reached are boolean, you automatically have shipped? and reached? methods.